# Filling a NSMutableArray not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Simple question but I don't get it.
I defined a

```
 @property NSMutableArray* Checkmarks;
```

in `myTableView.h`

and @synthesize it in myTableView.m In my table view I allocated it with

```
Checkmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in viewDidLoad() In didSelectRowAtIndexPath the Array is filled with

```
[Checkmarks addObject:myObject];
```

but my log says that `Checkmarks` is empty though `myObject` is not.

This only occurs in iOS9 but I don't know whats causing this or what changed.

Please help :)

Comment: Is Checkmarks _empty_ or _nil_? And shouldn't that be `self.Checkmarks`?

Comment: Post your full code so we can get a better picture of what's happening. Also, do you actually need the `@synthesize` statement?

Comment: `Checkmarks` is nil not empty

Comment: @TomWayne I doubt that iOS9 was the one that introduced a change. Please make the memory ownership explicit and remove the synthesize and use self.checkmarks instead and you will have that fixed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't need synthesize, you only need it when you provide a custom setter AND getter, and it seems that is not your case.

Second you should declare your properties with explicit memory ownership, therefore, you should have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *checkmarks;
```

When you remove your synthesize you can either do _checkmarks addObject or [self.checkmarks addObject:myObject].

Then try to print your checkmarks before and after your addObject. Checkmark has to print an empty array before the addObject and then has to have the object. Note that an empty array isn't the same as nil.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Checkmarks` is nil, it means that your alloc/init didn't work as you expected.

Your viewDidLoad should look something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.Checkmark = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

This should be in a UIViewController (including a UITableViewController) and *not* in a UITableView.

(Also worth noting: by convention, properties begin with a lower case letter and, as [Tiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34769863/2998) says, you should be explicit with your ownership, though I think the defaults mean this isn't your issue here.)

Comment: Yeah, by default it is strong now, at least last time I saw it, but I always recommend an explicit ownership since it is easy to do and not everyone knows the default xD